# CSS -- center div on page

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of "strips" of images that all add up to one image. Now I need to border the completed image and put that box in the middle of a html page.

No matter what I try, I can't seem to center the `<div>` that contains the multiple `<img>` tags. I'm looking for a purely CSS solution with as little text as possible (as I need to create a bash script that produces this page).

Thanks,
Milan

edit:

Apparently i need to provide code, eventhough it's very simple:

```
<html><head>
<style>div{font-size:0px; border: 5px solid red; display:inline-block;}</style>
</head><body>
<img ...><img ...><img ...><img ...> 
</body></html>
```

Comment: Well, You need to provide some code

Comment: If you're using margin:auto; to do the centering, make sure to add display:block; to your images because the auto centering only works on block elements

Comment: did you set a width to your div and tried to put it in 'margin: 0 auto;' ?

Comment: Do you know the final width of the div? IE: the sum of widths of all the images?

Comment: I guess my real problem is to get the border to fit around the imgs without using display:inline-block then? Becuase the inline is what's messing up the margins.

Answer (score 3):

```
div{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or, if you just want everything centered, use `text-align: center;` on the body.

Comment: 50%? Why would i do that? I want the <div> to be the exact width of all the images added together. Which works if i set it to display:inline-block; But the margin auto doesn't work.

Comment: then just use a div with no width and use `text-align: center`

Comment: Yeah i guess that's the only way. I was kinda trying to avoid that though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <div>This is the text to be centered</div>
</div>
```

To center horizontally, you can use the `margin: auto;` attribute in css

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#centeredDiv { margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a CodePen that I think will solve this issue. Basically you're going to want to use

```
style="text-align:center"
```

on the container div

http://cdpn.io/IhLBK

Comment: Inline styles are bad. See [Separation of presentation and content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content)